# Convert iOS project to 64 bit using ConvertCocoa64 script

Tags: ios, xcode, terminal, 64-bit, iphone-64bit

I need to convert my iOS project to 64-bit friendly (to get rid of compiler warnings, as in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30231614/how-to-remove-100s-of-warnings-implicit-conversion-loses-integer-precision-ns). The solution apparently is to run ConvertCocoa64.

I've managed to locate ConvertCocoa64 (which is no longer included in /Developer/Extras/64BitConversion/ConvertCocoa64) as the [Apple docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Cocoa64BitGuide/ConvertingExistingApp/ConvertingExistingApp.html) suggest, but [here](https://developer.apple.com/downloads/) (search for Auxiliary Tools)

So I've download the script. But my question is, how do I run this on my project? Please assume a total newbie level of knowledge here when it comes to the terminal and running scripts. Do I drop the script inside my project folder and just double click it? Or do I access it from the terminal? The docs say run this command:

```
/Developer/Extras/64BitConversion/ConvertCocoa64 `find . -name '*.[hm]' | xargs`
```

But since that folder doesn't exist, where do I run it?. I tried dropping the script in the Developer folder, but when I type ConvertCocoa64 it says command not found.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I'm not mistaking, to run script, you should place dot `.` before command. Doesn't really matters, where script is situated as long, as it doesn't rely on it heavily

```
> cd ~/path/to/script/dir/
> ./ConvertCocoa64 ...
```

Comment: Yep, it was the ./ that I needed. I dropped the script in the parent folder and then all worked

Answer (score 1):

Find where the command is located now.  You'll want to run it in the terminal using the full path to the command, as in your example, just with the real path.

A good way to get the full path is to locate the command in the Finder and drag it to an open terminal window - this also "escapes" any spaces in the path for you.  The easiest way to hit all your files as arguments to the command is to cd (change directory) to your project first (in the terminal).

This should get you set up to follow the directions you have.

Comment: Thanks - I think the main problem was running the script - but as Sergii suggested ./ did the trick. Upvoted though, as helpful nonetheless.

Comment: Yup either way will work- it's mostly preference.  You can also add to your path if you plan on using it a lot.